# Can a batch program do this to a CSV?

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have a CSV file problem and feel batch can help.
My CSV file has six values (%a-%f)
Among other problems is the fact that I have to manually create data in my CSV file cut and paste(caveman style) based off the first value, a string. 
The other values are integers so hopefully that simplifies my task.

Here is what I mean creating data manually based off %a

My %a string is ugly and counter like, it contains integers and hyphens

Example:

```
00-text-00-000
```

The format of the string I need for my %a is then such:

```
ww-xx-yy-zzz
```

Where ww,yy and zzz are counter like integers.
xx is the random text.

That's the setup to my problem, here is my main goal.

If the yy part of the %a in my CSV file is 01,02 or 03 I need those entire rows values copied and added to my CSV file as new data.However here is the real kicker.
the values of yy need to change now for the new data so its not a exact copy

```
01 needs to be 07
02 needs to be 06
03 needs to be 05
```

So that my CSV file starts with missing data like this:

```
00-text-00-000
00-text-00-001 
00-text-01-000
00-text-01-001
00-text-02-000
00-text-02-001
00-text-03-000
00-text-03-001
00-text-04-000
00-text1-00-000
00-text1-00-001 
00-text1-01-000
...
```

Afterwards it has new data for %a:

```
00-text-00-000
00-text-00-001 
00-text-01-000
00-text-01-001
00-text-02-000
00-text-02-001
00-text-03-000
00-text-03-001
00-text-04-000
00-text-04-001
00-text-05-000
00-text-05-001
00-text-06-000
00-text-06-001
00-text-07-000
00-text-07-001
```

The new rows will otherwise be identical other than the %a that changes every 01 to 07,02 to 06 and 03 to 06 as I previously stated.

But that's not all, the %b value also needs to change. Same number but with its sign reversed. So any %b that are negative turn positive and vice versa. 
So altogether my data starts like this:

```
00-text-00-000,1,2,3,4,5
00-text-00-001,-1,2,3,4,5
00-text-01-000,-2,-1,2,1
00-text-01-001,3,1,3,1
00-text-02-000,4,4,4,4
00-text-02-001,-4,-4,4,4
00-text-03-000,-5,-6,5,5
00-text-03-001,6,6,6,6
00-text-04-000,-6,-6,6,6
00-text-04-001,4,5,6,7
```

And ends like this:

```
00-text-00-000,1,2,3,4,5
00-text-00-001,-1,2,3,4,5
00-text-01-000,-2,-1,2,1
00-text-01-001,3,1,3,1
00-text-02-000,4,4,4,4
00-text-02-001,-4,-4,4,4
00-text-03-000,-5,-6,5,5
00-text-03-001,6,6,6,6
00-text-04-000,-6,-6,6,6
00-text-04-001,4,5,6,7
00-text-05-000,5,-6,5,5
00-text-05-001,-6,6,6,6
00-text-06-000,-4,4,4,4
00-text-06-001,4,-4,4,4
00-text-07-000,2,-1,2,1
00-text-07-001,-3,1,3,1
```

Is this even possible with batch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q36214264.csv"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.csv"
(
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1,2*delims=," %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 REM this reproduces the original line
 ECHO(%%a,%%b,%%c
 REM tokenise the first column
 SET "new1="
 FOR /f "tokens=1-4 delims=-" %%p IN ("%%a") DO (
  IF %%r==01 SET "new1=%%p-%%q-07-%%s"
  IF %%r==02 SET "new1=%%p-%%q-06-%%s"
  IF %%r==03 SET "new1=%%p-%%q-05-%%s"
 )
 REM calculate -%%b
 SET /a new2=-%%b
 REM new output - only if column 1 was changed
 IF DEFINED new1 ECHO(!new1!,!new2!,%%c
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q36214264.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

The processing is described by the comments.

Using `delayedexpansion`, you can access the values of variables as they change within a loop. It could also be done using subroutines.

This routine outputs data in a "raw" form. If you want it sorted, sort it.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the corresponding indices in the new YY parts
set "newYY[01]=07"
set "newYY[02]=06"
set "newYY[03]=05"

set "lastXX="
rem Read an input line and separate it in the specified tokens
(for /F "tokens=1-6 delims=," %%a in (input.csv) do (
   for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=-" %%w in ("%%a") do (

      rem If a new data set started
      if "%%x" neq "!lastXX!" (
         rem If there is new data from previous set
         if defined lastXX (
            rem Copy it
            for /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%m in ('set newData[') do (
               echo %%n
               set "%%m="
            )
         )
         rem Start the new set
         set "lastXX=%%x"
      )

      rem If this data must be duplicated
      if defined newYY[%%y] (
         rem Duplicate it, as specified
         set /A newB=-%%b
         set "newData[!newYY[%%y]!-%%z]=%%w-%%x-!newYY[%%y]!-%%z,!newB!,%%c,%%d,%%e,%%f"
      )

      rem Copy this data
      echo %%a,%%b,%%c,%%d,%%e,%%f

   )
)) > output.csv

rem Copy the new data from last set
(for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%n in ('set newData[') do echo %%n) >> output.csv
```